# C# unit testing for a NotFound via a GET

Tags: c#, rest, unit-testing

For some reason, I am having troubles making a unit test for the following in C#

```
[Route("api/Orders/{orderID:int}/Items")]
public OrderItemsDTO Get(int orderID)
{
    if (_orderItemsService.Get(orderID).Items.Count() == 0)
    {
          throw new HttpResponseException(
             Request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.NotFound, String.Format("Order {0} not found.", orderID)));
    }           

    return _orderItemsService.Get(orderID);              
}
```

I have a unit test running correctly for an Async Add which is what I'm using to Post that I was trying to base my unit test off of with some tweaks I thought it would work, but it doesn't. the following is what I thought should work:

```
   private OrderItemsController _testSubject;
   private Mock<IOrderItemsService> _moqOrderItemsService = new Mock<IOrderItemsService>();

    [TestInitialize]
    public void TestInitialize()
    {
        _testSubject = new OrderItemsController(_moqOrderItemsService.Object);
    }

    [TestMethod]
    [ExpectedException(typeof(HttpResponseException))]
    public async Task ThrowHttpResponseExceptionWhenThereIsAValidationException()
    {
        _moqOrderItemsService.Setup(ois => ois.Get(It.IsAny<int>()))
            .Throws(new ValidationException("test"));

        try
        {
            _testSubject.Get(17);
        }
        catch(HttpResponseException ex)
        {
            Assert.IsNotNull(ex.Response);
            Assert.AreEqual(HttpStatusCode.NotFound, ex.Response.StatusCode);
            throw;
        }            
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You set up order item service mock to throw `ValidationException` when it is called with any id. Then you are expecting controller to throw `HttpResponseException` which is not true - you will have same exception as you throw from service.

You should setup service to return some object (you didn't provide definition of service interface and types which it returns) with empty Items property:

```
_moqOrderItemsService.Setup(ois => ois.Get(It.IsAny<int>()))
     .Returns(/* some object with empty Items property */);
```

Now in controller you will go to throwing `HttpResponseException` path.

**Side note**: why are you throwing exceptions instead of returning something like `Content(HttpStatusCode.NotFound, "Message")`? You even can create base controller with method `IHttpActionResult NotFound(string message)` which will do this for you.

Comment: This confuses me because '[ExpectedException(typeof(HttpResponseException))]
        public async Task ThrowHttpResponseExceptionWhenThereIsAValidationException()
        {
            _moqOrderItemsService.Setup(ois => ois.AddAsync(It.IsAny<int>(), It.IsAny<OrderItemDTO>()))
                .Throws(new ValidationException("test")); ' Is in the working check for the AddAsync and it catches an HttpResponseEception and the unit test works just fine.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest not testing the Web API controller, rather test the _orderItemsService and mock out whatever repository you are using in the service. You can assert that the OrderItemsDTO is not null.

Well according to Microsoft testing controllers is best practice: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/testing-and-debugging/unit-testing-controllers-in-web-api.

Comment: Even link you provided states the opposite - it is useful to write unit tests for controllers and it shows different ways to do that. Controllers have logic which determine which type of response should be returned and which dependencies should be called. All this code should be verified

Comment: I meant this as in testing controllers, but I would rather test my services in isolation my controllers in any case is wrapping my services logic.

Comment: We determine the controllers responses by using the services logic. Thanks for the info though.